# Redirect subdomain to domain: unexpected result

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I made redirect of my forum from subdomain to the /forum/ folder with this .htaccess

```
#REDIRECT FORUM
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/forum/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Everything is fine but I get unexpected result with the request:

```
http://forum.example.com/forum/10  =>  http://www.example.com/forum/10
```

Have to be

```
http://forum.example.com/forum/10  =>  http://www.example.com/forum/forum/10
```

Where is a mistake?

Comment: The problem is: if REQUEST_URI is `/forum` and we need it to be redirected to `/forum`, the result should be `/forum/forum`. But we get only one `/forum` with above redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#REDIRECT FORUM
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/forum/forum/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Here is my [.htaccess](http://www.sathyasai.ru/htaccess-copy.txt) and you can try the link http://forum.sathyasai.ru/forum/31

Comment: I don't know why but /forum/forum/$1 eated to the single /forum too. I thought that the problem is the cache (php5-apc or browser), but restart apache didn't help.

Comment: May be the problem is hungry matching?

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess has few mistakes. I am putting here the corrected version of your .htaccess:

```
# OPTIONS
DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# REDIRECT FORUM
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum\.sathyasai\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.sathyasai.ru/forum%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# RUN OLD_SITE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v2
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/v2%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule (.*) /v2/$1 [L]

# RUN NEW_SITE
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: I just try to put only # REDIRECT FORUM section to clean .htaccess file and face the same problem with wrong redirection as described in my first message.

Also I noticed that it is correct to put 

    http://www.sathyasai.ru/forum%{REQUEST_URI}

than 

    http://www.sathyasai.ru/forum/%{REQUEST_URI}

otherwise we will get double slash after forum//

Comment: Yes you're right about not using / just before `%{REQUEST_URI}`. Also can you post your latest .htaccess again in your question.

Comment: The last version is here [.htaccess](http://www.sathyasai.ru/htaccess-copy.txt). It checks 3 sites on one domain 1) #OLD_SITE 2) #FORUM 3) #NEW_SITE. But the question is only to correct redirection of forum in #REDIRECT FORUM section.

Comment: This is not what I suggested in my answer above, there are quite a few mistakes in your .htaccess.

Comment: I try your code above, but it didn't help for my problem. There are few reasons why I keep my code on the site. First one, all urls with `/forum` have to be redirected to `/forum/index.php` only and not to the `/index.php`. After that I have to check, is there files from old site in `/v2` dir and redirect to it. The last one, redirect all requests to `/index.php`

Comment: Some rules form your .htaccess is difficult to understand e.g.: `RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]`. Also you need to tell about setup like what are respective DOCUMENT_ROOT configs for `forum.sathyasai.ru` and `www.sathyasai.ru` and in which .htaccess you've placed above code.

Comment: `forum.sathyasai.ru` have been moved to `www.sathyasai.ru/forum`. Both urls are alias now (in apache hosts settings and in domain DNS) and point to one dir in the server. But I need old links to be redirected to new urls as described in the first post.

Comment: thank you for `RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]`, changed to `RewriteRule ^ - [L]`

Comment: Just for testing can you comment out `RUN FORUM` and `RUN NEW_SITE` sections and then try my suggested code?